# Soft and hard delete Ruby on Rails

Tags: cascading-deletes

Ruby on Rails => Implement your own soft delete with the following features:

1. Should cascade delete
2. Should be able to permanent delete with a different method. We should have a method to soft and hard delete records.
3. Remember that the soft delete and hard delete should take care of dependent: :destroy associations as well. Also write tests for these.

Important: Do not use any gems for soft delete feature.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the interesting solutions you can try:

https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia